# SweetAlert confirm redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, sweetalert

I've got this function to reset the game *after* the user presses *delete* and then presses *ok*  again.

```
function confirmReset() {
  swal({   
          title: "Are you sure you want to reset your game?",   text: "You will not be able to recover your game!",
           type: "warning",   
           showCancelButton: true,   
           confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
           confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
           closeOnConfirm: false 
         }, function(){   
          swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"), 
            function(){
              window.location.href = "includes/php/reset.php?naam=<?php echo $naam ?>";
            }
      });
}
```

it works *if* i do the `window.location.href` at the place were the second *swal('deleted'... etc)* is at , but if i use a *second* function *after*  the user preses *OK* aswell it wont fire the `window.location.href`

Comment: Why not just use setTimeout and refresh page inside that to give time for second alert to show?

Comment: I tried that, it works. but it isn't pretty. If the user clicks the _ok_ button too early or too late it looks messy. I just want the page to _refresh_ / _go to the other page_ when the user clicks on the second _OK_  @charlietfl

Comment: Isn't there something like _onConfirm_ _window.location.hrefetcetcetc_ ? @charlietfl

Comment: Create a demo. Not clear why what you have wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
function confirmReset() {
  swal({   
          title: "Are you sure you want to reset your game?",   text: "You will not be able to recover your game!",
           type: "warning",   
           showCancelButton: true,   
           confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
           confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
           closeOnConfirm: false 
         }, function(){   
            swal({
                title: "Deleted!",
                text: "Your imaginary file has been deleted.",
                type: "success",
                //timer: 3000
            }, 
            function(){
              window.location.href = "/";
            })
      });
}
```

Comment: Already used something like that with _setTimeout_ , it works but it isn't clean. I want it to be set on the _OK_ button and _not_ with a timeout, if the user isn't payin attention I want the screen to remain that way _untill_ he/she clicks on _ok_

Comment: Ok no problem. comment the timer on second alert.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a conditional statement & .then, you can redirect on the "OK" Button, and no need to implement the timer. I use this particular method for API calls.

```
function confirmReset() {
      swal({   
              title: "Are you sure you want to reset your game?",   
              text: "You will not be able to recover your game!",
              type: "warning",   
              showCancelButton: true,   
              confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
              confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
              closeOnConfirm: false 
           }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                 Swal.fire(
                  'Deleted!',
                  'Continue to .....',
                  'success'
                 ).then(function() {
                window.location = "/";
               })      
        }
    }
```